# Introducing a simple count subquery to an already existing subquery

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am creating a simple image browser which is connected to an SQLite database. Within the browser, similar images are grouped into an **event** and each **image** is labelled with a few **tags**.

Someone helped me construct this very helpful query below. It contains 5 random tags as an example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         t.EventId,
         SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'necktie' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'necktie',
         SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'shirt' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'shirt',
         SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'suit' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'suit',
         SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'man' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'man',
         SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'male' 
     FROM 
         TagsMSCV t 
     WHERE 
         name IN ('necktie', 'shirt', 'suit', 'man', 'male') 
     GROUP BY 
         t.EventId) 
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(*) DESC
```

This returns how many of each tag (column is called 'name') show up in each event. However now I also need the size of the event (number of unique image id's in the event) which can be accomplished with the below query:

```
SELECT EventId, COUNT(DISTINCT ImageId) 
FROM TagsMSCV 
GROUP BY EventId
```

But I have no idea how to introduce this syntax into the subquery above? If I put it beside `t.EventId`, it only counts the image id's in event that are tagged with the 5 random tags which is not correct. I need the total unique image id's in the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your subquery is not necessary.  Second, you can use conditional `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
SELECT t.EventId,
        SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'necktie' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as necktie,
        SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'shirt' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as shirt,
        SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'suit' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as suit,
        SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'man' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as man,
        SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as male 
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN name = 'necktie' THEN imageid END) as necktie_images,
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN name = 'shirt' THEN imageid END) as shirt_images,
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN name = 'suit' THEN imageid END) as suit_images,
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN name = 'man' THEN imageid END) as man_images,
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN name = 'male' THEN imageid END) as male_images
FROM TagsMSCV t
WHERE name IN ('necktie', 'shirt', 'suit', 'man', 'male')
GROUP BY t.EventId
```

EDIT:

If you want the total distinct images for an event, then no conditional logic is needed.  Just use:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT imageid) as total_images,
```

And remove the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. What you are suggesting is only counting the total image_id's tagged with necktie, shirt, etc. I know how to do that. What I need is ALL the unique image_id's attached to the event_id.

Comment: You can see here https://i.imgur.com/xKFEAXy.png that your solution is only counting the image_id returned containing the 5 tags. In reality there should be 100's of unique image_id's for each event_id.

Comment: @AzzyDude . . . If that is the case, just remove the `WHERE` clause.  It doesn't affect the conditional aggregation columns, and the additional data will be used for the `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.

Comment: While that works, it has increased the response time by 5. Also it returns every event_id in the table even if it contains none of the tags. Maybe just keeping both queries separate and combining the data afterward is the best method?

Comment: @AzzyDude . . . You may not require the `DISTINCT` in the count.  My guess, though, is that the count is going to be expensive wherever you do it.

Comment: I think you are correct.  Thank you for your assistance.